# How to run function only once if an IF statement is true?

Tags: javascript

Somewhere in the code if an If statement is true, i want to call function that check something, could someone please show example ??
Thanks.

I want to turn on manager.on only once if the trade is going to be send, and after the manager says something like "trade accepted... continuing", then i want to turn off that manager.
The developer told that the manager shouldnt be turned on more times...

```
var offer = manager.createOffer(_message);
var _message2 = _message.slice(51, -15);
manager.getUserInventoryContents(offer.partner.getSteamID64(), 440, 2, true, function (err, myInv) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    // I need to send X ref
    var volume = amount; //put whatever amount
    // Filter out all the ref
    var ref = myInv.filter(function (item) {
      return item.market_hash_name.match('Refined Metal')
    });
    // Let the user know we don't have enough ref
    if (ref.length < volume) {
      console.log('Not enough ref');
      message.reply('<:false:750799883572609245> **You dont have enough items !!**')
      return true; // Give up
    }
    // Start a new trade offer
    // Add what we should to the current trade
    console.log('Adding '+volume+' metal');
    offer.addTheirItems(ref.slice(0, volume))
    // Send the offer
    offer.send(function (err, status) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log('Trade offer sent successfully');
        message.reply('Here is the offer: ' + '<https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/'+ offer.id+ '>');
        manager.on('sentOfferChanged', function(offer, oldState) {
          console.log(`Offer #${offer.id} changed: ${TradeOfferManager.ETradeOfferState[oldState]} -> ${TradeOfferManager.ETradeOfferState[offer.state]}`);
          if (offer.state == TradeOfferManager.ETradeOfferState.Accepted) {
            /*if(_message === ){}*/
            message.channel.send('<:true:750799921497505913> **Trade was succesfully confirmed**, generating random ticket from 0 to 100');
            number = randomNumber(0,120);
            number = (number < 100) ? number : number -20;
            message.reply('The ticket is: ' + number);
            if(number >= 50) {
              message.channel.send('Winning coin : <:redside:750060689296457749>');
              message.channel.send('**You lost <:sadpepe:752562873917505619>**');
              return;
            } else {
              message.channel.send('Winning coin : <:blueside:750059309915701308>');
              message.channel.send('**Congratulations, You won !! **<:superpepe:752563517986701469>');
              manager.loadInventory(440, 2, true, function (err, inventory) {
                if (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                } else {
                  // I need to send X ref
                  var volume = (amount * 2); //put whatever amount
                  // Filter out all the ref
                  var ref = inventory.filter(function (item) {
                    return item.market_hash_name.match('Refined Metal');
                  });
                  // Let the user know we don't have enough ref
                  if (ref.length < volume) {
                    console.log('Not enough ref');
                    return true; // Give up
                  }
                  // Start a new trade offer
                  var offer = manager.createOffer(_message);
                  // Add what we should to the current trade
                  console.log('Adding '+volume+' metal');
                  offer.addMyItems(ref.slice(0, volume));
                  // Send the offer
                  offer.send(function (err, status) {
                    if (err) {
                      console.log(err);
                    } else if (status == 'pending') {
                      community.acceptConfirmationForObject(config.identitySecret, offer.id, function(err) {
                        if (err) {
                          console.log(err);
                        } else {
                          console.log("Offer confirmed");
                        }
                      });
                    } else {
                      console.log('Trade offer sent successfully');
                    }
                  });
                }
              });
            }
            return;
          } else if (TradeOfferManager.ETradeOfferState[offer.state] === "Declined") {
            message.reply('<:false:750799883572609245> **Trade was declined, deleting the coinflip**');
            return;
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: give your function a name and call the function inside the if?

Comment: then it will be not once, or will be ???

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tfyso5g6/ , it will run once depending on your code, but i can't say that for sure since you didn't post any code, it is only guesswork without you providing your code

Comment: If you put together a snippet of code that demonstrates your issue then people will be more able to respond.

Comment: okay i will post the code here and show the example